# how to call a base class function in a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, abstract, cout

I have a base class called Employee, and a derived class StudentEmployee.

Employee class has a function called getEmployeeName() that returns a string.

in my StudentEmployee class I have a function called printInfo() and getPayRate()

and in the printInfo() function I get an error with this statement:

```
cout << getEmployeeName() << getPayRate() << "";
```

but I get a error with the << operators. do I have to create an object of the base class in my derived class to call that the base class function getEmployeeName() ? I feel like I should cast it but can not find any examples to help me

here is a short version

```
    #include<iostream>v
    using namespace std;
    class Base {
    public:
        void setBaseName(string name){
            baseName =name;
        }
        string getBaseName(){
            return baseName;
        }

    private:
        string baseName;
    };

    class Derived :public Base
    {
    public:
        void printInfo(){
            cout << getBaseName(); // I GET ERROR HERE
        }
    private:

    };
    int main (){
        Derived d;
        d.printInfo();
    system("puase");
    return 0;
    }
```

error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: You should *never* feel that you should cast.

Comment: You should be able to access all the non-private member functions of the base class in the derived class. Could you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Also post the exact error message you're getting

Comment: Your getEmployeeName() should work perfectly as is, but if you add the exact error it would be easier to understand

Comment: thanks for helping try to make it more understandable

Comment: Add `#include<string>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basename variable doesn't initializes with any value therefore when you call printinfo() the function getbasename() is unable to return anything.